# Is possible to know if process is Windows Service

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-services

I get details about my process, is it possible to get information about if such process in WindowsService or no?

```
$proc = get-process -Id 7120
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) cmdlet with the [`Win32_Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-service) WMI class:

```bash
# Obtain the process of interest.
$ps = Get-Process -ErrorAction Stop -Id 7120

# Try to retrieve the service that it belongs to, if any.
$svc = 
  Get-CimInstance Win32_Service -Filter "ProcessId = $($ps.Id)"

# Report the result.
if ($svc) {
  Write-Verbose -Verbose "Process with ID  $($ps.Id) belongs to service `"$($svc.Name)`"."
} else {
  Write-Verbose -Verbose "Process with ID  $($ps.Id) does not belong to any to service."
}
```